# How to align text if language is not English using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have multiple HTML cards. I want to align the text inside the cards like if card title text language is urdu or arabic language then the text is automatically set to `align-right`. If the card title text is in English then I want to set `align-left`.

Is this possible using jQuery or javaScript? Does anybody have the solution? I would be grateful for any help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (language === 'ur') {
    $('.title').css('text-align', 'right');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hpanel blog-box">
  <div class="title">
    <h4>اسلام آباد: پاکستان ٹیلی کمیونکیشن اتھارٹی (پی ٹی اے) نے اسلام آباد ہائیکورٹ کو آگاہ کیا ہے کہ اس</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hpanel blog-box">
  <div class="title">
    <h4>I'm not entirely sure what's going on, especially as the value in the dictionary has been updated.</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can check first character of string, if is english then change direction

Comment: can you explain with code how can you check character?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `dir` attribute to `RTL` (**Right To Left**) for `Urdu` or `Arabic` text like so

```
<div dir = "RTL">
   <!-- Your Urdu/Arabic text -->
</div>
```

Checkout this fiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c8oqft1x/4/) and [this](https://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/) also

Comment: you mean every time i need to define the direction attribute inside HTML code. this is not the solution for me. if the database has multiple card then what should i do?

Comment: `I have two HTML cards` this is in your question

Comment: My Question is updated please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can check first character of string, If first character is english than change direction to left. In this case, i used regex to checking first character of string.

Although this way is not perfect but can help you.

```js
$(".blog-box .title").filter((i, ele) => {
  return $("h4", ele).text().trim().match(/^[A-Za-z0-9]/);
}).css({
  'text-align': 'left',
  'direction': 'ltr'
})
```

```css
.blog-box .title {
  text-align: right;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hpanel blog-box">
  <div class="title">
    <h4>اسلام آباد: پاکستان ٹیلی کمیونکیشن اتھارٹی (پی ٹی اے) نے اسلام آباد ہائیکورٹ کو آگاہ کیا ہے کہ اس</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hpanel blog-box">
  <div class="title">
    <h4>I'm not entirely sure what's going on, especially as the value in the dictionary has been updated.</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (language === 'ur') {
    $('.title').css('text-align', 'right');
    $('.title').css('direction', 'rtl');
  }
})
```